# how to save multiple tables using Spring boot JpaRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have Two Tables Those are User and UserDetails.

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

private String userName;

private String password;

}


@Entity
public class UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String address;

private Date birthday;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

}
```

there is not show getters and setter.

I am using spring boot for creating my application. when I go to save `User`, I want to save those two tables in same time. It means first save `User` table and then I  save `UserDetails` table (to save `UserDetails` table, `User` table primary key is required). how I do this thing using spring boot JPA repository? Another thing, in case `UserDetails` table is not saved, we want to roll-back our whole transaction (it means we have to rollback user table).

this is my services class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    void saveUserDetails(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName,
            String address, Date birthday) {
        User n = new User();
        n.setUserName(userName);
        n.setPassword(password);
        UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();
        ud.setFirstName(firstName);
        ud.setlastName(lastName);
        ud.setAddress(address);
        ud.setBirthDate(birthday);
        userRepository.save(n);
        userDetailsRepository.save(ud);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a silly change in your entity classes

- In `User`, class added a field with respective getter and setter which is mapped by `UserDetails`

  ```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
  private Collection<UserDetails> userDetails;
  ```
- In `UserDetails` class, add an extra annotations with field `user`. like:

  ```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="id")
  private User user;
  ```

For rolling back while unsuccessful transaction you can add `@Transactional` annotation in your service layer (where you have called `.save()` or `.persists()` method).

Comment: thanks for the answer.  when i go to save `userDetails`  table i want to `user` table id. but how i get user id. there two table want to save same transaction.

Comment: yes,but it not working. i think i make mistake inside the service class. but i can not find it. i put my service class in above (bellow the question)

Comment: thanks for your help. i found my mis point 
    User user = userRepository.save(n);
    ud.setUser(user);